# Finding last cell with content in a column -> why is my version of the code giving an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the last cell containing information in a specific column and have found the below listed solution in another thread. However I tried to do it without defining 'ws as Worksheet'.
If I do this, the compiler does not accept '.Rows' within .cells(). Why?

Additional question:

1. In the first version, what does 'Set' do exactly? Why do i need this?

**Code found in thread:**

```
Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xrowrange As Range
Dim xrowprint As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Database_UtilAnal")
With ws
Set xrowrange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
Set xrowprint = xrowrange.Rows
End With

End Sub
```

**My code:**

```
Sub testprint_UtilAnal_Alt()

Dim xrowrange As Range
Dim xrowprint As Long

xrowrange = Sheets("Database_UtilAnal").Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
xrowprint = xrowrange.Rows

End Sub
```

Comment: It errors because you got rid of the `With...End With` block as well. `Set` is used for object variables. Note that the thread code is also bad. `xrowprint` is declared `As Long` and code attempts to `Set xrowprint`. Anyway, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The first code will work if you change to xrowprint=xrowrange.Row (Without Set, and without s)

Comment: Ok. You are right, i had changed the code that i found in the thread and build in this error. Changed it again, thanks.

Regarding 'With...End With':
I thought that this allows me to refer to the sheet (in this case), so that this reference does not have to be repeated for all range variables that are coded within 'With... End With' and the code is thus shorter and better readable. Is that wrong?
Sorry for the trivial quesitons, Im just starting out :)
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. No problem, we all started somewhere! `.Rows.count` refers to the *sheet's* rows, i.e. the `ws` in `With ws`. The period in front is your clue. You've gotten rid of the `With` and `End With`, hence your issue.. See how the `With...End With` is used in the posted answer, so that `.Rows.Count` refers to `Sheets("Database...")`, as does the outer `.Cells`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Last Cell/Row in Column

Like you use **Set** for **workbooks** and **worksheets**, you have to use it for other **objects**, too, e.g. **ranges**.

If you need the **last cell** (object) in column "**B**", you can use this:

```
Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

    Dim xRowRange As Range

    With Sheets("Database_UtilAnal")
        Set xRowRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    End With

    Debug.Print xRowRange.Address

    Set xRowRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you need only the **last row** (number), you can use this:

```
Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

    Dim xRowPrint As Long

    With Sheets("Database_UtilAnal")
        xRowPrint = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Debug.Print xRowPrint

End Sub
```

The following two versions demonstrate how to get one by using the other:

```
Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

    Dim xRowPrint As Long
    Dim xRowRange As Range

    With Sheets("Database_UtilAnal")
        Set xRowRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        xRowPrint = xRowRange.Row
    End With

    Debug.Print xRowRange.Address
    Debug.Print xRowPrint

    Set xRowRange = Nothing

End Sub

Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

    Dim xRowPrint As Long
    Dim xRowRange As Range

    With Sheets("Database_UtilAnal")
        xRowPrint = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set xRowRange = .Cells(xRowPrint, "B")
    End With

    Debug.Print xRowPrint
    Debug.Print xRowRange.Address

    Set xRowRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second block of code for the **lastrow number** is exactly what I needed!
One last question:

I still have some understanding issues with the 'With...End With'. To my logic, it should be possible to leave out 'With...End With' and instead do this:

    `Sub testprint_UtilAnal()

        Dim xRowPrint As Long
    
        xRowPrint = Sheets("Database_UtilAnal").Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
        Debug.Print xRowPrint

    End Sub`


Why does this give me an error?

Comment: @Leo Schmid: I have seen many codes like what you are proposing but you have to use Rows.Count without the first dot (.): xRowPrint = Sheets("Database_UtilAnal").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row where the only slight inprecision is the Rows.Count which refers to any sheet that is active at the moment. In practice it might fail only if you are opening  workbooks with different sizes of the maximum row e.g. Excel 2003 and Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. It perfectly answered my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not executing is because of `Sheets("Database_UtilAnal").Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)`

The failing piece being **.Rows.Count**

The best way to imagine this is by visualizing a `With` statement. For all sakes and purposes, you can say that a `With` statement will append the parameter of said statement to any leading "."

That is to say

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .Range("A1")
End With
```

Is the same as

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

So why doesn't `Sheets("Database_UtilAnal").Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)` execute successfully?

Notice the leading "." at `.Rows.Count`. Without a `With` statement, the compiler doesn't see anything to append to that, and therefore it cannot execute.

**EDIT:**

The `Set` keyword is used to assign objects (such as `Range("A1")`) to certain non-primitive datatypes (such as a `Range`).

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a perfect explanation of how to understand the dot-operator. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!